# Vlookup... two unique identifiers...two sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two different spreadsheets:

- The first includes customer numbers, effective dates and actual release date.
- The second includes customer numbers, effective dates and close dates.

The unique identifiers are combined if customer number AND effective date. I need to pull in the corresponding close date for each customer/effective date on the release date sheet.  How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you'll need to make a slight addition to the second spreadsheet. I'll explain how I'd do this:

Assume Workbook1 has a single sheet, Sheet1, that contains (Column Letter):
(A)Customer Number, (B)Effective Date, (C)Actual Release Date

Assume Workbook2 has a a single sheet, Sheet1, that contains (Column Letter):
(A)Customer Number, (B)Effective Date, (C)Close Date.

In order to make this work, you'll need to add a new column to Workbook2, which combines Customer Number and Effective Date.  You can do this a number of ways, one way would be to insert a new column at the beginning of the sheet and in the second row of that column (assuming the first row is the label, "Key") enter the following formula:

=B2&C2

Then drag that down to fill the appropriate number of rows. So now Workbook2 has the following columns:
(A)Key, (B)Customer Number, (C)Effective Date, (D)Close Date

Now, in the first Workbook, you'll add your column where you want the close date to appear, assuming it's at the end, Workbook1 should now have:
(A)Customer Number, (B)Effective Date, (C)Actual Release Date, (D)Close Date

Then, in D2 (again, assuming you have a row at the top that contains the labels), you'd enter the following formula (Change 9999 below to the lowest row in Workbook2):

=VLOOKUP(A2&B2,'C:\Path\To\Workbook2\Workbook2.xlsx'!Sheet1:$A$2:$D$9999,4,FALSE)

And drag that down to the last row in your table.

This will cause VLOOKUP to look in Workbook2, Sheet1. It will match the combination of Workbook1, Sheet1, A&B for that particular column against the key column in Workbook2, Sheet1, which is also a combination of the same information, and will return the closing date, which is contained in column 4 of Workbook2, Sheet1.

I'm writing this on the fly, and don't have excel at the ready to test it, but that should work.